# Looping through to hide/show all UIButton controls in a group

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uibutton

I would like to be able to use a loop to tell a certain group of UIButton to hide. Normally I would write:

```
  a.ishidden = true
  b.ishidden = true
  a.ishidden = true
```

I am looking for a way to write what I am writing in a shorter quicker way.

Comment: Add all your button to array, and for-each

Comment: Put them in an array? Put them in [Outlet Collection](https://medium.com/@bfozdar/outlet-collections-a70b09ca61a3)

Comment: Do you have these buttons in an array or you can fetch them from its `superView.subviews` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner, nice and simple

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f].forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create button **outletcollections** and with a for loop, you can achieve this

```
for i in buttoncollections {i.isHidden = true}
```